# Laravel : convert grouped data to one row

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, group-by

Hello please i want to convert grouped data with duplicated keys and different values to one row.
For example :

```
    "book1" {
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "group" : "book1",
        "name" : "Book X",
        "buy" : "null",
        "test" : "null",
    } ,
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "group" : "book1",
        "name" : "null",
        "buy" : "100",
        "test" : "null",
    } ,
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "group" : "book1",
        "name" : "null",
        "buy" : "null",
        "test" : "344",
    }
 },
    "book2" {
 {
        "id" : "1",
        "group" : "book2",
        "name" : "Book Y",
        "buy" : "null",
        "test" : "null",
    }
    ....
 } 
    ...
```

what i want to do is convert all this arrays with common key to one array or one row in the database where data are grouped like the example the data are grouped by group field
and what i want to do is like that :

```
{
  "id" : "1",
  "group" : "book1",
  "name" : "Book X",
  "buy" : "100",
  "test" : "344",
}
```

Please could you help to fix by php code (laravel model) or SQL query and thank you so much !

Comment: how you getting this data ? from query ?  is that 3 rows in `book1` ?

Comment: yes and 3 fields changed for each array as foreach time only one of this field is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $data = []; // your data
    $response = [];
    foreach($data as $key => $d){
       if($d['id'] != null) $response[$key]['id'] = $d['id'];
       if($d['group'] != null) $response[$key]['group'] = $d['group'];
       if($d['name'] != null) $response[$key]['name'] = $d['name'];
       if($d['buy'] != null) $response[$key]['buy'] = $d['buy'];
       if($d['test'] != null) $response[$key]['test'] = $d['test'];

    }
```

**EDITED**

you have use `" "` fo null so use like below

```
$response = [];
        foreach($data as $key => $d){
           if($d['id'] != "null") $response[$d['group']]['id'] = $d['id'];
           if($d['group'] != "null") $response[$d['group']]['group'] = $d['group'];
           if($d['name'] != "null") $response[$d['group']]['name'] = $d['name'];
           if($d['buy'] != "null") $response[$d['group']]['buy'] = $d['buy'];
           if($d['test'] != "null") $response[$d['group']]['test'] = $d['test'];

        }
```

EDITED 2

```
$response = [];
            foreach($data as $key => $row){
                $array = [];
               foreach($row as $d){
                if($d['id'] != null) $array['id'] = $d['id'];
                if($d['group'] != null) $array['group'] = $d['group'];
                if($d['name'] != null) $array['name'] = $d['name'];
                if($d['buy'] != null) $array['buy'] = $d['buy'];
                if($d['test'] != null) $array['test'] = $d['test'];
               }
              $response[$key][] = $array;
            }

    dd($response);
```

Comment: no no it's not working . the result is not including or showing the 3 fields (name, buy and test)

Comment: check answer i have edited , you have put `'' '` for `null`  check the conditions properly and different way

Comment: i edited the exemple could you re check it please ?

Comment: Yeahh thank you so much just i changed null to empty()

Answer (score 0):

use groupBy()

```
$data = App\ModelName::groupBy('test')->get();
```

Comment: i used to show multi arrays with null fields what i want to is merge those arrays or replace it with 1 array and neglected the null fields like the exemple

Comment: i have updated above answer please check and use groupBy with test